# Creating a django rest API for my python script

Tags: python, django, mongodb, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a JSON file with data as such :

```
['dbname' : 'A', 'collection' : 'ACollection', 'fields' : ['name', 'phone_no', 'address']}
['dbname' : 'B', 'collection' : 'BCollection', 'fields' : ['name', 'phone_no', 'address', 'class']}
```

These are 2 examples amongst many other dictionaries of the same format.

I have a python code that does the following : Accepts 2 inputs from the user - phone_no and dbname. For example, the user enters phone_no as xxxxxxxxxx and dbname as A. The python code then reads the JSON file and matches the user input with the dictionary element having the name of the database as 'A'. It then opens the database 'A', opens the respective collection 'ACollection' and prints the respective fields of posts within the collection that have the phone_no value as xxxxxxxxxx. The databases are implemented with mongoDB.

I need to build a django rest api for this code. The end goal is to access the code from a browser. The user provides the 2 inputs in the browser and the code is executed, returning the data, which is displayed on the browser. I have gone through the django-rest framework documentation but I'm new to this whole concept and would like some guidance.

How do I implement these functions and create an API? What code should the models, serializers, views and urls files have related to my program?

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class App(object):
        def __init__(self, phone_no, name, address, categories):
                self.phone_no = phone_no
                self.name = name
                self.address = address
                self.categories = categories
```

This is what I'm working with so far, to get started. The problem, however, is that the models class should essentially be dynamic. Ex: If 'A' is the database, the program returns 3 fields but if 'B' is the database, the program returns 4 values so I'm not sure what the models class would be like.

views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from pymongo import Connection
from models import App
from serializers import AppSerializer
import json
import pymongo
from os import listdir
import re
from django import forms


@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def pgs(request):
    #connect to our local mongodb
    db = Connection('localhost',27017)
    #get a connection to our database
    dbconn = db.general
    dbCollection = dbconn['data']

    if request.method == 'GET':
        #get our collection
        items = []
        for r in dbCollection.find():
            post = App(r["phone_no"],r["name"],r["address"],r["categories"])
            items.append(post)
        serializedList = AppSerializer(items, many=True)
        return Response(serializedList.data)
```

Comment: Do you have any initial code for the data model? That might be a good place to start and could get some more specific questions going.

Comment: So far I have a basic API set up that merely retrieves data from the database and displays it. I'm trying to figure out how to get the phone_no input from the user in the browser and use it to query the posts in the database

Comment: Great. If you've got a database, you've got at least a start on a data model.  Do you have a Django model class for this yet or is it still just a db schema? Either way, let's start by looking at that.

Comment: I've added the models.py class

Comment: Great. Now, when you say "databases" do you actually mean different database connections, or just different sources in the same database?

Comment: Different database connections. 'A' and 'B' are separate databases

Comment: I've added the views file also. How do I get a user input when I execute the program? I want the user to input phone_no and use that to query the databases. How can the user enter a phone number in the browser that can be used by the program?

Comment: See the example, it shows one method: retrieving the value from the GET request. You may prefer this criteria to be built into the path and should work through the tutorial to understand how urls are matched and unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have identical tables in two different databases. We'd start by creating two db connections in settings.py. Let's say those are called db_a and db_b. We might model this as so:

```
class PhoneGenome(models.Model):
    phone_no = models.CharField(length=255)
    name = models.CharField(length=255)
    # and so on...
    class Meta:
        # if database pre-exists, may want to use managed=False
        managed = False
```

This gives us a model. Now we choose which database to pull from based on user input. In a view, you might have something like:

```
db_used = request.GET.get('database')
db_conns = {'a': 'db_a', 'b': 'db_b'}
if db_conns.has_key(db_used):    
    records = PhoneGenome.objects.using(db_conns[db_used]).filter( user_criteria_here)
```

The using() method in your queryset is what allows you to select which database to run the query against.

There's a lot to manage here potentially, so this would be a good time to look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/

And if you haven't already, you really should work through the Django tutorial at the very least before going much further.

Comment: The difficulty is, each database does not have identical tables, some of them have 3 fields, some of them have upto 10. There are also more than 10 databases with an inbuilt functionality to add new databases so it doesn't make sense to create a model for each database manually. Also, I just added db_used = request.GET.get('database') to my existing views.py file but there is no prompt for a user input in the browser

Comment: Fair enough. I think you'll probably find that Django is the wrong tool. It's a lot of overhead just to build out one JSON interface... especially if you're not even going to use built-in models. Instead, I'd look at Flask to serve your view(s) and rely on a more programmatic way of accessing your data, such as SQL Alchemy.